# Magento 1.9.2.2 emails not sending

Tags: email

sorry but im really quite new to magento.

Recently all emails stop sending from my site.

Emails are generated in core_email_queue but are not sending.

I have cron jobs configured and i have installed scheduler
[image]

Does anyone know what I need to do